# How to Access Magento Rest API in iOS swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, api, magento2

I am write code to post data from Magento REST API for IOS Application put get me error. I try from login and register view controller in the same code get me the same error 
The api Magento REST API . I success to get data from api but error to post data in api

```
    self.internetConnectionChecker { (status) in
    if status{
    KVNProgress.show();
    let userLoginApi = "http://3.85.198.62/4apps/rest/V1/integration/customer/token"
                    let parameters: Parameters = ["username": username, "password": password]
                    let header : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
                    Alamofire.request(userLoginApi, method: .post, parameters: parameters,  headers: header).responseObject {  (response: DataResponse<User>) in
                        KVNProgress.dismiss()
                         print(response.request?.url)
                        print(response.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields)
                        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                        print(json)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                loginCallback(response.result.value!)}
                            self.maincontroller.SuccessMessage(title: "تسجيل الدخول", successbody: "")

The Output 
{
    message = "Decoding error: \nUnable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error\n#0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer/Json.php(64): Magento\\Framework\\Serialize\\Serializer\\Json->unserialize('password=Abc%40...')\n#1 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(141): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Deserializer\\Json->deserialize('password=Abc%40...')\n#2 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(199): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request->getBodyParams()\n#3 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(97): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request->getRequestData()\n#4 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#5 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callParent('resolve', Array)\n#6 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#7 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('resolve', Array, Array)\n#8 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->resolve()\n#9 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#10 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#12 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#14 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(137): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#16 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#17 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/4apps/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#18 {main}";
    trace = "<null>";
}
```

Comment: what Alamofire version are you using? and can you share `User` code ?

Comment: pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2' import Foundation
import ObjectMapper


class User : NSObject, NSCoding, Mappable{
    
    var addresses : [AnyObject]?
    var createdAt : String?
    var createdIn : String?
    var disableAutoGroupChange : Int?
    var email : String?
    var extensionAttributes : ExtensionAttribute?
    var firstname : String?
    var groupId : Int?
    var id : Int?
    var lastname : String?
    var storeId : Int?
    var updatedAt : String?
    var websiteId : Int?
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see has happened on the Magento side `Decoding error: \nUnable to unserialize value...` It points to the problem unserializing JSON params. So I've tried to play with encoding on the Alamofire request and `URLEncoding.queryString` works for me. Here is my code

```
Alamofire.request(userLoginApi, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: header).responseData {  (response: DataResponse<Data>) in
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
    print("json", json)
}
```

Comment: @shahed-abo-saleem by the way, I'm starting to develop open-source Magento app so you may find it useful at some point https://github.com/troublediehard/swift-magento-app